# Android 4.4 setOnItemLongClickListener bug?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, onlongclicklistener

I have a ListView with a `setOnItemClickListener` and `setOnItemLongClickListener`.
Since 1 year no problem with it. But with Android 4.4 I'll get with a LongClick both Methods executed.

For example:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1,int arg2, long arg3){
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);      
            final String Name = lv.getAdapter().getItem(arg2).toString();               

            // Make sth on click
        }});


        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    final int arg2, long arg3) {
            // Make sth on longclick
            }
        });
```

On long click both will be executed. Is this a bug or a problem with my code?

Comment: "On long click both will be executed". nope one one will be executed depending on the click and this  `ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);` is not required could use `arg0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no problem with your code it's just that you haven't returned a value on your onItemLongClick boolean. Change it into:

```
    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        final int arg2, long arg3) {
                // Make sth on longclick

                return true;
                }
            });
```

This will prevent long click on doing further actions since take note that a longclick is still a click which is why onclicklistener triggers on this event.

Comment: Thanks, in my code I hade `return false`. Changed it to `return true` made it!